# How to stay sane with ExpressionEngines ambiguous channel field IDs?

Tags: expressionengine

When writing queries or running through result sets, I'm constantly having to refer to fields as "field_id_X". I want to believe there is a saner way to go about this than defining a CONST for every field_id/name pair.

```
define(NAME_FIELD ,'field_id_3');
define(HEIGHT_FIELD, 'field_id_4');

foreach( $result as $row ){
    $name = $row[NAME_FIELD]; // :(
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get an Array for field id's and names...

```
function getFieldReferences() {
    $sql = "SELECT field_id, field_name
        FROM exp_channel_fields
       WHERE site_id = ".$this->EE->config->item('site_id');
    $result = $this->EE->db->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $result->result_array();
        $finalResult = array();
        foreach ($result as $row)
            $finalResult[$row["field_id"]] = $row["field_name"];

        return $finalResult;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Example conversion of a specific entry details $entry_id...

```
$sql = "SELECT exp_channel_data.*, exp_channel_titles.*, exp_channels.channel_name
          FROM exp_channel_data, exp_channel_titles, exp_channels
         WHERE exp_channel_data.entry_id = $entry_id
           AND exp_cart_products.entry_id = $entry_id
           AND exp_channel_titles.entry_id = $entry_id
         LIMIT = 1";
$result = $this->EE->db->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $result->result_array();
        $result = $result[0];

        //###   Get Field Titles   ###
        $fieldReferences = getFieldReferences();

        //###   Replace Field ID reference with name   ###
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            if (substr($key,0,9) == "field_id_") {
                $result[$fieldReferences[substr($key,9)]] = $value;
                unset($result[$key]);
            }
            if (substr($key,0,9) == "field_ft_")
                unset($result[$key]);
        }//###   End of foreach   ###
}
```

Convert Member fields to names based on specified member $id...

```
$sql = "SELECT m_field_id, m_field_name
      FROM exp_member_fields";
$result = $this->EE->db->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
    $memberFields = $result->result_array();

    $sql = "SELECT exp_member_data.*, exp_members.email
          FROM exp_member_data, exp_members
         WHERE exp_member_data.member_id = $id
           AND exp_members.member_id = $id
         LIMIT 1";

    $result = $this->EE->db->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
    $result = $result->result_array();
    $rawMemberDetails = $result[0];

    //###   Loop through each Member field assigning it the correct name   ###
    foreach($memberFields as $row)
        $memberDetails[ $row['m_field_name'] ] = $rawMemberDetails['m_field_id_'.$row['m_field_id']];
}
```

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't come to this

Comment: For the first part, you could use the expressionengine `field_model`. Something like: `$fields = $this->ee->field_model->get_fields($channel_id)->result_array();`

Answer (score 0):

You could look up **exp_channel_fields.field_name** (or field_label) by the **field_id** you have from **exp_channel_data**.

Comment: I would love to see a specific example of your recommendation!